# Finding period of $f$ using the functional equation $f(x) + f(x+a+b) = f(x+a) + f(x+b)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations, periodic-functions

> Assume that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, and $f(x) + f(x+a+b) = f(x+a) + f(x+b)$ where $|f(x)|\le 1 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ($a > b$).
>
> Find the period of the function $f(x)$.

My approach:

$$f(x+a+b) - f(x+a) = f(x+b) - f(x)$$

After this, I tried replacing $x $ with $x+a $and several other substitutions but couldn't reach a conclusive result. Also, I'm not sure how to use $ |f(x)|\le 1 $ to get the function's period.

Of course, the aim is to establish a result of the form $f(x+T) = f(x)$.

It'd be great if someone could give a detailed solution. Thanks a lot!

$f(x)$ is not a constant function. If it is, prove it to be so.

Edit:
The problem is a modified IMO 1996 shortlisted problem. In that problem, $a$ and $b$ had specific values ($\frac16$ and $\frac17$), but I wish to generalize the problem for any two constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What if $f(x)=c$ where $|c|\le 1$?

Comment: That's just one possibility

Comment: Try $a=\sqrt{2}, b=1$ and $f(m\sqrt{2}+n)=1$ for integer $m,n$, $f(x)=0$ for all other values of $x$.

Comment: Let $g(x):=f(x)-f(0).$ What do you know about it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. All I can say is that |f(x) - f(0)|≤2

Comment: Are you sure there's no additional information about a and b?

Comment: There's no additional information given for the answer will be in terms of a and b

Comment: This question is very very very similar to an IMO short listed question of 1996, with a and b given as 1/6 and 1/7. I've solved that, but now I'm having a really hard time generalizing it. I hope someone answers..

Comment: @Rick That makes a lot more sense: there **is** a positive period, while the words "the function's period" above imply that it's uniquely determined by $a,b$, and that't not true.

Comment: @Professor Vector Can you please answer this question?

Comment: @Rick As I said, there can't be a unique solution for the period in the general case, when $b/a$ is irrational, and I'm not sure it is possible to prove even the existence of a period, then, though I can't give a counterexample, either. Without some clarification by the OP (source of the problem, at least, or left out assumptions), I'm not sure I want to waste too much time on it, sorry!

Comment: @Professor Vector oh yes, you're right. Even I felt data is insufficient at first, that's why I asked the OP if there's more information on a,b.

Comment: @Professor Vector, the problem is a modified IMO 1996 shortlisted problem. In that problem, a and b had specific values (1/6 and 1/7), but I wish to generalise the problem for any two constants a and b. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @schrodinger_16 Perhaps start a bounty for this question? I think even you're getting stuck at T = ma = nb? Like professor vector said, it can't be generalized for a/b irrational, but maybe it can for the ratio being rational?

Comment: @Rick I can prove it if $b/a$ is rational, but not in general, and I doubt it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x+a+b) - f(x+a) = f(x+b) - f(x)\tag1$$ for all $x\in R$. Then,
$$f(x+a+nb) - f(x+a) = f(x+nb) - f(x)\tag2$$ for all $x\in R$ and all natural $n$, as we can show by induction: it's trivially true for $n=0$. Let's assume (2) is true for $n=k$:
$$f(x+a+kb) - f(x+a) = f(x+kb) - f(x)\tag3$$ for all $x\in R$. Replacing $x$ by $x+kb$ in (1), we obtain $$f(x+a+(k+1)b) - f(x+a+kb) = f(x+(k+1)b) - f(x+kb)\tag4$$ for all $x\in R$, and adding (3) and (4) gives
$$f(x+a+(k+1)b) - f(x+a) = f(x+(k+1)b) - f(x)$$ for all $x\in R$, i.e. (2) for $n=k+1$, proving the induction step.
With exactly the same reasoning, exchanging the roles of $a$ and $b$, we can extend that to $$f(x+ma+nb) - f(x+ma) = f(x+nb) - f(x)\tag5$$ for all $x\in R$ and all natural $m,n$.
Now let's assume $b/a$ is rational, i.e. $b/a=m/n$ for some natural numbers $m,n$. That means $$ma=nb=c\tag{period},$$ and for those $m,n$, (5) becomes
$$f(x+2c)-f(x+c)=f(x+c)-f(x)\tag6.$$ Adding $f(x+c)-f(x)$ on both sides of (6), we obtain $f(x+2c)-f(x)=2[f(x+c)-f(x)]$, and using induction, again, we can derive
$$f(x+nc)-f(x)=n[f(x+c)-f(x)].$$ So we have
$$|f(x+c)-f(x)|=\frac1n|f(x+nc)-f(x)|\le\frac2n$$ from the assumption $|f(x)|\le1$, and since that is true for all natural $n$, we must have 
$$f(x+c)=f(x)$$  for all $x\in R$, i.e. $f$ has period $c$.
The assumption that $b/a$ is rational is essential: the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac12\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}ax+\cos\frac{2\pi}bx\right)$ obviously satisfies (1) and $|f(x)|\le1$ for all $x\in R$, but it's periodic if and only if $b/a$ is rational, as can be seen by assuming $f(T)=f(0)=1$, implying that both $\cos\frac{2\pi}aT$ and $\cos\frac{2\pi}bT$ have to be $1$, i.e. $T/a$ and $T/b$ have to be integers.

Comment: What is c? Any positive rational number? or any positive integer?

Comment: ok, so T = LCM(a,b) Makes sense. Thanks alot!! I wasn't able to interpret that T = ma = nb when I tried it :)